# how to make image at top of bottom sheet in android

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]how to place the image at top center of the bottom sheet and half of image should be in  outof layout,,,i had attached sample image

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_25"
 android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_25"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_25">

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
     android:id="@+id/iv_success_image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tick" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/nilu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This does not use bottom sheet and just adds image at the center of the screen. Not useful